# react-native-webview: mixedContentMode not working

Tags: react-native, react-native-webview

I have a webview inside my app and it works well, both in ios and android, when I am using secure urls (https).

But one of the backend enviroments uses unsecure http protocol and it doesn't work on Android. I've already set `android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"` on **main/AndroidManifest.xml** and the website indeed opens, but it doesn't load correctly because it mix secure and unsecure requests inside it.

I've tried to add the prop `mixedContentMode={'always'}` but it didn't affected the behavior I am trying to avoid.

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding these props as well:

```
javaScriptEnabled={true}
domStorageEnabled={true}
startInLoadingState={true}
originWhitelist={['*']}
```